# Ionic 2 & Angular 2 - Two Components in another one

Tags: angular, web, ionic2

I am using ionic2 for a mobile app.
Now I want to use that app in desktop browser but the design is not awesome.

I would like to show two components on one page. Is it possible ?
For example by include two @Component in another one ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

your parent component HTML should be ...

```
<component1></component1>
<component2></component2>
```

Comment: Based on value of `selector` in component. And you'll have to declare those in `@NgModule` under `declarations` and `entryComponents` even no need to import them on your parentpage